# Reading from GEXF using GraphStream (Not a regular file error)

Tags: java, gephi, graphstream

I am trying to reproduce [this example](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Reading-files-using-FileSource/) of reading a GEXF file using GraphStream, but it gave me this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: not a regular file 'sources\small-world-1.gexf'
at org.graphstream.stream.file.FileSourceFactory.sourceFor(FileSourceFactory.java:83)
at pack.age.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

This is my code :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "sources\\small-world-1.gexf";
    Graph g = new SingleGraph("g");
    FileSource fs = FileSourceFactory.sourceFor(filePath);

    fs.addSink(g);

    try {
        fs.begin(filePath);

        while (fs.nextEvents()) {
            // Optionally some code here ...
        }
    } catch( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        fs.end();
    } catch( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fs.removeSink(g);
    }
}


}
```

This is the project's hierarchy :

[image]

What did I do wrong ? And how can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your 'filePath' string looks wrong. Paths have to be relative to the root of the eclipse project or be absolute. Try "src/pack/age/sources/small-world-1.gexf".

Comment: That was it @Yoann thanks!